# ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis with decode and case in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle, date

I am putting fromdate and todate as parameter I want to get the previous month date of fromdate  and when todate not the date in same month of fromdate I need to put last date of the fromdate month but if todate is date in month of fromdate I need to put it as it is,  when user put for example from 1-1-2016 to 25-1-2016 I will get previous month 1-12-2015 to 25-12-2016 of the from month and I need to check the todate if it is in same month of fromdate  I will keep it but if it not for example from 1-1-2016 to 25-4-2016 I will make it 30-1-2016.
I am trying to use decode and case but in both am getting same error 
ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

my query In case

```
 select (case ( when (LAST_DAY(TRUNC(TO_DATE(:fromdate ,'DD-MM-YYYY') , 'Month')) <> (TO_DATE(:fromdate ,'DD-MM-YYYY')))  
then (DATE between ADd_MONTHS(TO_DATE(:fromdate ,'DD-MM-YYYY') , -1) and LAST_DAY(TRUNC(TO_DATE(:todate ,'DD-MM-YYYY') , 'Month')))
else (DATE between ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(TO_DATE(:fromdate ,'DD-MM-YYYY') , 'Month'),-1) and TO_DATE(:todate ,'DD-MM-YYYY'))
 end))
 FROM  dual;
```

my query in decode

```
select DECODE((TO_DATE(:fromdate ,'DD-MM-YYYY')) , LAST_DAY(TRUNC(TO_DATE(:fromdate ,'DD-MM-YYYY') , 'Month')) , 
(DATE  between ADd_MONTHS(TO_DATE(:fromdate ,'DD-MM-YYYY') , -1) and ADd_MONTHS(TO_DATE(:todate ,'DD-MM-YYYY') , -1)) ,
(DATE between ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(TO_DATE(:fromdate ,'DD-MM-YYYY') , 'Month'),-1) and TO_DATE(:todate ,'DD-MM-YYYY'))
FROM  dual ;
```

Comment: ?? What you have after THEN and after ELSE are Oracle "conditions" (logical expressions). Same in DECODE - the last two values are "conditions" (... between ... and ...)  Plain Oracle SQL doesn't have Boolean values. What is your CASE/DECODE expression supposed to return?

Comment: You requirement is not clear. You said when :todate is not the last day in **that** month I need to put as last date of the month. First, when you say **that** month, what are you referring to? The month of :fromdate? of :fromdate minus one day? Anyway, in your EXAMPLE the result is 30-1, which is NOT the last day of any month. It would be best if you show a table with :fromdate, :todate and desired result with several rows showing how your logic works (no code needed).

Comment: @mathguy i did some update , and i will give u an example if i put  from 1-1-2016 to 20-1-2016 no changes should be i will take previous month of the both parameter but when to date in different month  from 1-1-2016 to 20-6-2016 i should change to date to last date of previous month  then it will be 1-1-2016 to 31-1-2016

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select
    to_date(:from_date) "Original From",
    to_date(:to_date) "Original To",
    case when trunc(to_date(:from_date),'MONTH') = trunc(to_date(:to_date),'MONTH')
         then add_months(to_date(:from_date),-1)
         else to_date(:from_date)
    end "New From",
    case when trunc(to_date(:from_date),'MONTH') = trunc(to_date(:to_date),'MONTH')
         then add_months(to_date(:to_date),-1)
         else add_months(trunc(to_date(:from_date),'MONTH'),1)-1
    end "New To"
from dual;
```

---

I've put to_date around all the bind variables as it was using SQL Developer strings as input.